# Unable to Enable Access Management on an existing 9.5 Content Manager Sidebar

Tags: sites-9.5, azure, access-management

As per below Article we executed below script, after doing that also we were unable to see Access Management navigation in Content Manager Sidebar(on the left side slide-out navigation menu).
Can you please suggest how to resolve this issue.

```
SetupAccessManagement.ps1 -Authority http://localhost:85/access-management
```

[enabling access management on an existing 9.5 content manager](https://docs.rws.com/816112/771081/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/enabling-------------access-management-on-an-existing-9-5-content-manager)

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors in either in browser console or in CMS event viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved after updating manifest.xml as suggested by RWS Support from below path
%TRIDION_HOME%\web\SDL\manifests\wcm\manifest.xml
below given configuration with Access management URL, restarted services and Reset IIS.

```
<applicationEntryPoint id="AccessManagement" title="Access Management" domainId="local" url="http://access.tridion.com/access-management/" icon="/WebUI/Editors/CME/Themes/SDL/Images/Icons/access-management.16.mono-bright.png" external="true"> 
<translations> 
<title lang="de">Access Management</title> 
<title lang="es">Gestión de acceso</title> 
<title lang="fr">Gestion des accès</title> 
<title lang="ja">Access Management</title> 
<title lang="nl">Toegangsbeheer</title> 
<title lang="zh">访问管理</title> 
</translations> 
</applicationEntryPoint>
```